# How to find out which distribution(sample) a number is coming from?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have two data samples of the same size N generated from two separate distributions, and a new number is given. How could I find out which distribution this new number is coming from? What should I do if the sample size were different?

My first thought is to compare the empirical probabilities based on these two samples, but I am not quite sure if it is the optimal solution. I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: What do you know (or are willing to assume) about these distributions?

Comment: @Bay I was only given two data samples.

Answer (score 1):

Given $x$, we compare $P(D_1|x)$ and $P(D_2|x)$ and decide which has a higher value.

To compute these values though, some assumptions and prior knowledge are required.

From Bayes' rule, this is equivalent to comparing $P(D_1)P(x|D_1)$ and $P(D_2)P(x|D_2)$. We have to make assumption about $P(D_i)$.

Comment: +1 — that was what I was getting at in my comment too — just the data is not enough